# Method from mock object not being called

Tags: googletest, googlemock

I have this code.
I have a real object, that is initialized with a mock object.
When I call a method from the real object that should call a method from the mock object, it doesn't call the method from the mock object, but from the base class.
Why doesn't it calls the method from the mock object, how could I fix this?

Thanks

```
class Parent
{
public:
   virtual bool verify() const;
};

class MockParent : public Parent
{
public:
   MOCK_METHOD(bool, verify, (), (const, override));
};

class MyObject
{
public:
   MyObject(Parent parent) :_parent(parent) {}
   Parent parent;

};

class Testclass : ::testing::Test
{
   TestClass() : mockParent(), myObject(mockParent) {}

   MyObject myObject;
   MockParent mockParent;
};

TEST_F(Testclass , test1)
{
// here I assume that it should call the method from the mock
   EXPECT_CALL(this->myObject.mockParent, verify()).WillOnce(testing::Return(true));

//call method from myObject that calls parent.verify
}
```

Comment: this->myObject.mockParent : myObject has no member mockParent..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the polymorphic call to trigger, you need to pass a pointer or a reference to the base class, not the base class directly:

```
class MyObject
{
public:
   MyObject(Parent& parent) :_parent(parent) {}
private: // members are usually private
   Parent& parent;
};
```

this will allow you to have the proper method being called. Also, please keep in mind that `Parent` should outlive `MyObject` (so that you will avoid the dangling reference error).

Some additional notes: it's best to keep a pure virtual base class:

```
class ParentBase
{
public:
   virtual ~ParentBase() = default;
   virtual bool verify() const = 0;
};
```

and have both `Parent` and `ParentMock` to inferit from `ParentBase`. This enforces better separation of concerns - your classes will then deal with interfaces, not implementations.